# Content-Security-Policy: default-src *

Tags: security, iframe, content-security-policy

I started exploring Content Security Policy on a website which uses inline scripts and other crimes. I configured CSP per header field like this:

```
content-security-policy: default-src *; frame-ancestors 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com cdn.jsdelivr.net *.stripe.com; report-uri https://sentry.io/api/x/csp-report/?sentry_key=y
```

My problem now is that the browser complains with the following message:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *"

I read the documentation for [`default-src <source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/default-src) which states that `<source>` can be one of the following sources:

- `<host-source>`
- `<scheme-source>`
- `'self'`
- `'unsafe-inline'`
- etc.

It seems to me that the asterisk can only be used for host sources. But what else can I do since only one `<source>` seems to be allowed? `default-src * 'unsafe-inline'` would not be compliant, right?

My goal basically is to use a minimal CSP configuration which works (and can be embedded via *iframe*). I am aware that it's best practice to go on with specific rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems to me that the asterisk can only be used for host sources.

Yes

> But what else can I do since only one `<source>` seems to be allowed?

Multiple `<source>`s are allowed.

> `default-src * 'unsafe-inline'` would not be compliant, right?

It’s compliant.

You can use https://cspvalidator.org/ to check. Or https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/.

But you really want to avoid specifying `'unsafe-inline'` in any CSP policy. Using `'unsafe-inline'` pretty much defeats the entire purpose of CSP.

What you want to do instead for any inline scripts causing CSP errors is: take the scripts out of your document and move them into separate files. That’s sort of the whole point.

But if you really must specify `'unsafe-inline'`, then as far as the dealing with the specific error cited in the question, you should only specify `'unsafe-inline'` for `script-src` — because the error message says, *“Refused to execute inline **script**.”*

If you instead specify `'unsafe-inline'` for `default-src`, then that causes the browser to fail to do CSP checks for *any* inline resources in your document — stylesheets, etc., too, not just scripts.

So if the only problem is an inline script and for some reason you can’t fix that by moving the script out to a separate file, or specifying a hash or nonce for it, then you should at least only specify `'unsafe-inline'` for `script-src`.

Comment: Using  `Header set Content-Security-Policy default-src * 'unsafe-inline'` causes a 500 error for me.